# once added,how to get back the original images using matlab?

Tags: image, image-processing, matlab

```
      A = imread('ab.jpg');
      A = imresize(A,[255 255]); subplot(2,2,1), imshow(A);
      B = imread('cd.jpg');
      B = imresize(B,[255 255]);subplot(2,2,2), imshow(B);
      C = imadd(A,B);subplot(2,2,3),imshow(C);
```

This is the program i have used to add two images and it is working fine. Now i want to get back both the images. Am not able to figure out how to get it back without taking one of the images as reference (ie subtracting image A from the sum to get image B). Can anyone please help?

Comment: If someone adds two numbers, and gives you only the sum, would you be able to recover each number?

Comment: @LuisMendo: We're of two minds! ;-)

Comment: tell me too if you can recover at least one image :)

Comment: If the data is `uint8`, even if you do use `A` or `B` you might not get back the correct values for the other image due to over flow.

Answer (score 2):

Let's not worry about images. Say I have two real integers, `x` and `y`. I add them to get `z = x+y`. Now if I tell someone the integer `z` is there any way for him or her to get back `x` and/or `y`?

Answer (score 0):

Potentially you can retrieve one of the numbers out of the summation, by having the other. But the issue you're facing with is the fact that your image matrices cannot exceed the value 255 since MATLAB uses `uint8` type by default. Here is an example for two corresponding pixels in image A and B:

```
% A(1,1) == 130 is ture
% B(1,1) == 180 is ture
C(1,1) = A(1,1) + B(1,1); %C(1,1) == 310 is false! c(1,1) == 255 is true
expectedB = C(1,1) - A(1,1); % expectedB == 180 is false! expectedB == 125 is true
```

You can cast the type of your matrices to `int16`. Whereas by doing so MATLAB's functions sich as `imshow` do not work as you want them to. Because they assume that your